# PermGen space issue for only one workspace of myeclipse

Tags: java, myeclipse, permgen

I am using myeclipse for development purpose and now when I try to run one project and getting PermGen Space issue. But If I run other project from dffrent workspace it works fine. I am using same tomcat for both.

Myeclipse.ini is:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.i18n.win32.win32.x86_64_3.2.0.v201103301700
-vm
binary/com.sun.java.jdk7.win32.x86_64_1.7.0.u45/bin/javaw.exe
-install
C:\Users\pratiks\AppData\Local\MyEclipse Professional 2014
-vmargs
-Xmx768m
-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m
-Dosgi.nls.warnings=ignore
```

Comment: you're getting the error in tomcat or in eclipse?

Comment: I am getting it in myeclipse

Comment: Are you sure your system have enough memory upto 2048m? You will get this error on startup if it doesn't

Comment: I have started it with 512m then 1024 and now on 2048.

Comment: I have enough memory.

Comment: You don't say what the issue is. Generally, you shouldn't need MaxPermSize anywhere near that high. Java 8 removes that parameter so perhaps try updating to MyEclipse 2017 (2014 isn't fully supported now).